# not equal to in mongo db in nested fileds

Tags: mongodb

I have one Collection which has nested Field, How can I apply not condition
[image]
I want to apply this query on this collection

```
select * from crawled_jobs where coordinates 0!= 0 and 1 != 0
```

In some record has not coordinates and there is log and lat is 0

Answer (score -1):

```
db.crawled_jobs.find({loc:{coordinates:{$nin:[0,0]} }});
```